# Configuring default static routes with RIPv2

Tags: linux, virtualbox, router

I am currently working on an assignment managing a smaller virtual network with virtual box and tiny core Linux. (Using quagga)

I am supposed to let RIP handle the default routing, though I cannot figure out how to do it. I've come across two commands that would do this, `default-information originate` and `redistribute static`. I did however not understand how these worked, even after searching some examples, which led me here.

PS. The NAT connection comes in on gateway, and router3 is not connected to the network, so disregard that.

[image: The network in question]